# Struts web application with React

Tags: java, reactjs, jsp, struts

I was working with an **ASP.Net** application with a **React UI** for a while, and I liked what I saw.

My main development is **Java + Struts**. I'm wondering, does anyone have any experience combining the two? Can they work together, is it worth the effort, or are they 2 separate beasts.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Of course they're "two separate beasts", one is a server-side web app framework, one is a client-side UI library(/framework). Struts can return JSON as well as anything else (w/ some fighting if you're seriously discussing Struts 1, which... don't use that, pretty easily if you're discussing Struts 2).

Comment: this is so common. clients with legacy application often request how to revamp the app because it's starting to "show its age"

this has been useful to me in particular

https://medium.com/better-programming/dont-be-afraid-of-legacy-how-to-gradually-introduce-react-js-in-a-really-old-application-79876c0dfa42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm not crystal clear about what you are asking,
But if you expecting some answer for building a web application with ReactJs and Struts, the simple answer is obviously we can build,

Implement your Struts APIs that return only data, then write ReactJs components to consume the same.

However, it will be a little more different than working with struts + JSP.

Usually, Struts + JSP is doing HTML templating on the back-end. So data are injected into HTML on server and HTML is also the format that is returned from the server.

React is client-side HTML templating library. So it is expected to communicate with the server via AJAX calls and reading data (in JSON or other formats) and inject that data on the client using React. So This is a huge shift from the web application architecture point of view.

In Struts2 you can implement RESTful API via struts2-rest-plugin. This article will help you get some idea about it
https://www.concretepage.com/struts-2/struts-2-rest-web-service-integration-example

Btw the thing is, Is it really worth spending time for struts while [Spring boot](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-react-full-stack-crud-maven-application) playing a major role in java based web development.

Comment: My apologies for not being very clear. I'm experienced with Struts2 + JSP, and my question was mainly if and how react can fit in.

Comment: Implement your Struts APIs that return only data, then write ReactJs components to consume the same